# Structural sheaf of a submanifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I am currently studying some topics in Algebraic Geometry, Algebraic Surfaces to be precise, and I have some doubts about the identity which I am going to write down.
To fix notations, let $X$ be some manifold and $Y\subset X$ a submanifold of codimension 1.
One defines the *structural sheaf*   $ \mathcal{I}_Y$ by setting the following ideals $I_Y(U)=\{f\in\mathcal{O}_X(U)\ |\ f(y)=0\ \forall\ y\in Y\}$ and then the usual restriction maps.
Now, one has that $Y$ is an effective divisor on $X$, that $\mathcal{I}_Y(U)$ consists of those functions having a zero along $Y$ and finally that locally each $f\in\mathcal{I}_Y(U)$ is such that $(f)-Y\ge0$.

I should conclude that $\mathcal{I}_Y=\mathcal{O}_X(-Y)$.

I am not even sure of what this identity implies. Does this mean that this sheaf is equal to the one built out of the sections of the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_X(-Y)$, the latter coming from the homomorphism $Div(X)\to Pic(X)$? Should I recall that $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}(-Y))\cong L(-Y)$, the latter being the Riemann-Roch space of $-Y$ and then use some isomorphism with $L(-Y)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the isomorphism $\operatorname{Div}(X) \to \operatorname{Pic}(X)$ you refer to? Once can define this isomorphism precisely by mapping an effective divisor $Y$ to $\mathcal{I}_Y^{-1}$.